# How do I directly access the php script without rerouting the URL to Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, url-rewriting

I am trying to find a way that I can allow direct access to a given php script without having to reroute that URL to the Codeignitoer's URL rewriting conventions or through its controllers.

Any way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd have to set it in the .htaccess file

The default .htaccess file just needs to have an ignore line inputted for a directory to NOT route through codeigniter:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt|**YOUR FOLDER TO IGNORE HERE**)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

For example putting: `RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt|custom_scripts)`

Would allow access at the URL: `http://example.com/custom_scripts/**any file you want**`

The codeigniter directories themselves have .htaccess files in them that deny outside access, so unless you want to exit those, this is the best way to do it.

Comment: I cannot believe I didn't think of htaccess! Thank you!